# Force unbind Mac from Open Directory from command line

Tags: macos, active-directory, unbind

Is it possible to force unbind a Mac from Open Directory using command line? I have seen it for AD using dsconfigad but not for OD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

sudo dsconfigldap -r ServerAddress